# Zend Navigation issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-navigation

I'm using Zend navigation to display menu items on the site.

in below bootstrap function,  what does it mean by 'layout' in
$this->bootstrap('layout') ? Is it layout file name with path ?, since i have several modules, its bit confusing.

```
protected function _initNavigation()
{
    $this->bootstrap('layout');
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
    $view = $layout->getView();             
    $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml', 'nav');

     $container = new Zend_Navigation($config);

     $view->navigation($container);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout is the site template that will be present in all site pages.

(To make it simple : for example you have a header and footer that will be present in all website pages, you put them in a layout and they will automaticaly included in all the pages)

For more informations on Zend Layout see [Zend Layout Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.layout.html)

**Edit :**

You can specify on layout for all modules, or you can make one layout per module (it is your choice and it depends on what you want to)

Comment: Is it the layout file name of that particular module?

Comment: The default layout is usualy named layout.phtml and placed in application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml

Comment: Layout of this particular module reside in, layouts/pbo/pbo.phtml, so I gave like this $this->bootstrap('pbo/pbo'). 
But it throws an error
Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'Resource matching "/pbo/pbo.phtml" not found'.........

Comment: ah my mistake I didn't understand you well.
No it doesn't take the layout path, it takes the ressource name in the application.ini file (wich is always layout) just leave it as it is.

Comment: My layout name is pbo.phtml, how can i use that?

Comment: You have to define it as the default layout in your application.ini (resources.layout.layout = pbo)

Answer (score 1):

> $this->bootstrap('layout') ? Is it layout file name with path ?,

This means that Zend first will bootstrap Zend_Application_Resource_Layout

More you can find here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.layout